# React Navigation method passed with navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass a method with navigation props from root. I have a few ideas from vanilla javascript to defining routes in react-navigation, but I'm not sure if it's a good way. How should I do that gently?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find it useful. I have a base screen class and all my other screens inherit from it:

```
export default class BaseScreen extends React.Component {
    static screen;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        BaseScreen.screen = this; 
    }

    nav() {
        return this.props.navigation;
    }
}

export default class HomeScreen extends BaseScreen {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

And now, doesn't matter where I am, I can just call:

```
BaseScreen.screen.nav()
```